# Is it possible to listen to keypress events from a (CORS) iframe in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, keypress

I'm NOT asking for a standard event listener. I know I can do `document.addEventListener('keypress', myfunction)` etc

I actually want to listen to the keyboard, so anytime the enter key is pressed, I want to trigger a function.

the reason I can't do the above is that I have a cross origin iframe inside my document so putting the event listener inside `componentDidMount` function, only fires when I do `keypress` in "my code", it's not responding to the embedded iframe

I also cant attach the event listener to the iframe as this violates CORS. anyone know a way I could just fire my function on keypress in another way?

thanks

Comment: Kinda defeats the purpose of CORS, doesn't it?

Comment: I feel like this question is speciically about handling events across iframes.. not keyboard listeners or react

Comment: @azium Me too. I updated the title and tags ^_^ If it were possible to add a global "keyboard" listener, that might be an *approach* to solve the goal.

Comment: I don't know if this will work, kind of shooting a blank here, did you try embedding the CORS iframe inside another iframe and then picking up events on the parent iframe?

Comment: I just want to listen to the enter key being pressed anywhere on my page. I don't care about my component or the iframe, so to speak, just that if enter is pressed, I respond

Comment: @Ivan86 that isn't a bad shout, I might try that but I'm not sure it would pick up the event would it?

Comment: @azium nothing really to do with handling events. I know I can't do that with CORS and if the iframe was mine I'd use crosswindow.  I need to just listen straight to the keyboard

Comment: @user2864740 yeh a global keyboard listener sounds like it would work, is there such a thing? :D

Comment: Also please note that `keypress` event is [Deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event)

Comment: `keydown` then.

Comment: @RedBaron Oh ok, I thought you wanted to catch the key event only on the CORS iframe. It would be easiest if you would make an example here or on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @Ivan86 I don't think it'll be easy to make a js fiddle as the iframe is not mine. put simply, I want to listen to when a user does a keypress anywhere whilst on my page, obviously it's easy without the embedded iframe